# Using ImageJ API to develop image processing software

Tags: java, image, image-processing, imagej

I am doing a research on content based image retrieval. I am hoping to develop web based image retrieval system. At the moment I am evaluating different image retrieval methods in CBIR. I want to use imagej to develop this web application but I am new to imagej and have no idea how to do this.

As a starter I want to read an image and extract color features of that image. First I am going to use color moments as image features.

I want to use the imagej api and code this process into a java web application and automate the feature extraction process.

I have no idea where to start. If you can provide simple code examples how to start this process I can learn along the way.

Comment: Why would you want to use ImageJ? Why not use the built-in ImageIO APIs?

Comment: Dear friend, Actually my supervisor asked me to study imagej. He said that there are many plugins that have functionality specific to CBIR operations which can be direly applied in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

ImageJ is a desktop application and software library written in Java. While it can be [used as an applet](http://imagej.net/applet/), I would not recommend that approach for a modern web application.

Instead, you could implement a simple Java web server (using [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) or similar) and write a Javascript client which runs in the web browser. But you would still have the problem of transferring your data between client and server. And image data—particularly scientific image data—can be very large.

Is there some reason in particular that your program *must* be a web application specifically? Automating tasks such as feature extraction within ImageJ is quite doable via macros and scripts, executed within the application UI itself, or [headlessly via the command line](http://fiji.sc/Headless).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am hoping to develop a web based CBIR. That is why the application should be a web application. I am not hoping to use imageJ as an applet instead I was hoping to use it as a library in my application itself. Because the imagej source is available. I now know how to do it. It's just that any example code of familiar image processing operation would be helpful to head start. Unless I have to read the whole api code and its time consuming. I am actually struggling against the deadline.